# How to dynamically add text into base64 image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64

I have a function that generates qr code png as base64 from a given URL.
When I put the data coming out of this function into an  src It renders the image. I would like to add some text into this image as well so that it writes some description underneath the QR code.

Here is the function:

```rb
  def generate_qr(model)
    url = model_url(model)
    require 'barby'
    require 'barby/barcode'
    require 'barby/barcode/qr_code'
    require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'

    barcode = Barby::QrCode.new(url, level: :q, size: 10)
    company_name = Base64.encode64("#{model.company.name} - #{model.name}")
    qr_output = Base64.encode64(barcode.to_png({ xdim: 10 }))
    "data:image/png;base64,#{qr_output}"
  end
```

How can I append the `company_name` variable underneath my qrcode.png so that when they download the image text is also in the image?

This did not work.

```
qr_output = Base64.encode64(barcode.to_png({ xdim: 10 }) + company_name)
```

Neither this:

```
qr_output = Base64.encode64(barcode.to_png({ xdim: 10 }) + "#{model.company.name} - #{model.name}")
```

Comment: I would probably look into ImageMagick since that's pretty much the typical way people do image manipulations

Comment: If I can do it without adding another dependency, I'd prefer doing it that way. Thanks for the recommendation.